# Let I be the midpoint of the side [AB]. Consider the point J of the segment [BC] st: BJ=2JC and $\angle AIC=\angle BAJ$ find angle $\angle{BAC}$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let ABC be a triangle and I be the midpoint of the side [AB]. Consider the point J of the segment [BC] st: $BJ=2JC$ and $\angle{AIC}=\angle{BAJ}$
Find $\angle{BAC}$

**My attempt:**

I tried solving the problem many times but couldn't come close to an answer. I'd like your help.

Comment: Have you made a figure ? What is the approximate value of this angle ?

Comment: How did you try solving? Can you pls share?

Comment: Hint: Let $K$ be $CI\cap AJ$. From the ratios, what two segments (besides $AI,BI$ are equal)? From the angle condition, what other two segments are equal? If those three segments are equal, what could you say about $\angle BAC$?

Comment: So Far from my previous work , i found that $AK = IK$ , and that the angle $\angle{CKJ}=\angle{AKI}$, however i can't find a relation between the ratios and the lengths . Is There a theorem  application i'm missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please note that the diagram is just a rough image of the question.

Draw $JD \parallel AB$

And label the sides as shown in the image.

Then you $JD=\frac{y}{3}$ (As $\triangle JDC$ is similar to $\triangle BIC$)

As $\triangle AIE$ is isosceles $IE=EA=3a$

And from triangle similarity you of $\triangle JDE$ and $\triangle AIE, ED=a$

Again from similarity of $\triangle JDC$ and $\triangle BIC, CD=2a$

Now you can see that $IE=AE=EC=3a$

Now it's all about angle chasing,

$\angle AEC=2b, \angle EAC=90-b, IAC=b+90-b=90$

Comment: oh , i see , clever manipulation .Thank you for the answer sir.

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure to help you